# Where is this sculpture of the ten commandments from?

Tags: identify-this, religion

I saw this picture of a group (which I blurred out) in front of a sculpture of the ten commandments on social media, and am wondering where it might be from. I might expect it either to be in the Americas in or Asia/Oceania, but I'm not sure, and I'm not really in a position to ask the original poster and expect a reply.

[image]

Comment: go to google.com and click the amazing IMAGE SEARCH feature.

Comment: @JoeBlow: I tried that before posting this question, and came up with nothing. Currently the only result is this webpage. (For what it counts, Google Image Search _has_ been useful a few times when I wanted to know where some photos of people I knew on Facebook were from, but couldn't be bothered to ask in person.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It would appear to be the ones put up in [San Mateo, Rizal, The Philippines](http://noypicollections.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/largest-ten-commandments-tablet.html).

> The largest ten commandments tablet was presented to Guinness World
>   Records at HalleluYAH Prayer Mountain For All Nations in San Mateo,
>   Rizal, Philippines on April 11, 2009. The tablet measured 65.04 square
>   meters (700.08 square ft), organized by Sister Grace Galindez-Gupana,
>   a businesswoman and founder of  the HalleluYAH Prophetic Global
>   Foundation. The tablet is located on top of HalleluYAH Prayer Mountain
>   and can be seen from the road.

Photos on the page seem to match the one you show, although theirs was taken when the tablets were new -  they've clearly been around a few years in the photo you provide.

Comment: Ah, you just beat me to it ;)

Comment: @Bernhard actually took me a while to find - there seem to be a lot of them out there!

Comment: The new largest one was made/purchased/organized by the same person.

Comment: using reverse google image search, I confirmed with [this blog entry](http://omionabike.blogspot.com/2013/08/when-shirley-turned-into-cyclocross.html).